# SILVERLIGHT CUSTOM templated control GetTemplateChild()

Tags: silverlight, custom-controls

I want to retireve control from ControlTemplate located in the resource dictionary. I have completed these steps :

1. I have set the defaultstylekey property.
2. I am trying to retrieve the control in an override method of OnApplyTemplate();
3. I am still getting null results

How is it possible ? Ive read about 25 articles about this and it to be a common problem and everybody just posted a message that they've finally done it but didn't post the solution to this problem . Thanks for your advice

Comment: Is your template in generic.xaml, or are you setting it in code?

Answer (score 0):

RESOLVED

I forgot that the control must be added to parent control and loaded. I've also used UpdateLayout() method before manipulating with the controls from template.